Copy Location Offset not working
Hi I am running Blender 4.0 on a windows 11 machine, I am trying to add the copy location constraint to a cube.
Using an empty as the target and enabling the offset so the cube is back at the starting point.  but it doesn't appear to be working correctly for me.  When I select the target the cube moves to that position.  However when I select the offset it doesn't return to its original position
Starting point

I have tried all the various options within the constraint itself but nothing seems to return it.  The YouTube videos I have watched have no issue with this feature?
My end goal is to move several objects and have a lower influence for each item,
Thanks for all help.
Here is the project


Are you sure you aren't thinking of a Copy Transforms constraint? If you set that with Target to Local and Owner to World then I'm pretty sure this achieves the effect you're looking for.

It should work, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

I have added the file, I must be doing something wrong but I just can't see it.

Offset will work as if you designate the target as the new world center of the object, so the object will be as far from the target as it is from the world center, if the target is at the center of the world the object won't move, but it's away, the object will move accordingly.
The Copy Location works basically by these two formulas if you leave everything to the defaults like using all axes, inverting none, Target and Owner both at World Space and Influence at 1 (for simplicity's sake):
When the Offset option is disabled, the Owner's location is ignored:
$$\text{new location}=\text{location}(Target).$$
When Offset is enabled, the Owner's location gets added to the Target location:
$$\text{new location}=\text{location}(Target)+\text{location}(Owner).$$
So if there is a Cube at world center (0, 0, 0) like in your question and an Empty at (3, 2, 1), without Offset the new location is simply
$$\begin{split}\text{new location} = Empty = \begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}.\end{split}$$
But even with Offset enabled and taking the Cube's location into account, since it is at the world center and $x+0=x$, the result is the same:
$$\text{new location} = Empty + Cube = \begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\1\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$

If on the other hand the Cube would be somewhere else like (-1, 0, -2) instead and the Empty at (3, 2, 1), this would make no difference with Offset disabled because the Cube's location will be ignored and replaced by the Empty's:
$$\begin{split}\text{new location} = Empty = \begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}.\end{split}$$
However enabling Offset will now make a difference: when you add the Cube's location which is now $\neq$ (0, 0, 0) to the Empty's location (or in this case subtract since two values are negative), the result differs:
$$\text{new location} = Empty + Cube = \begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\1\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\-1\end{pmatrix}.$$


Would you mind if I add some maths and images to it to visualize what's going on? It's not a different answer, so I would rather not post a second one here.

No problem..........  ;)
